# Is there a java client for Google Dataflow to start a job from template?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-java-client

I am looking up the way to start a Google dataflow job from template. I found the rest api to do so and dig into the api page 
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/apis
and only found the rest api to do so. I am wondering if there is some java client like what we can do in Storage such as

`Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();`

Maybe I overlooked. But the Api for Java and Python looked like all about Beam pipeline not starting a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing would be the [Google Cloud Java API Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) used with the Dataflow REST API.